# Docker bind mounts working on odbc.ini files on windows hosted but not on linux

Tags: docker

For last few days I've been struggling with configuring Informix ODBC properly for ASP.NET Core app hosted on linux (debian to be precise) containers.

Everything works fine when I copy .odbc.ini file to /root directory during build:

```
COPY ./.odbc.ini /root/
```

But since config files contain passwords I don't want to ship those files in images, would much rather mount them from host directory:

```
--mount type=bind,source=/usr/local/app/odbc/.odbc.ini,target=/root/.odbc.ini
```

This kind of binding works fine when running on Docker for Windows on development machine, but when trying it on Docker on Fedora29 I get an error:

```
is not listed as a dbserver name in sqlhosts.er][Informix]Server cms_net
```

The error only occurs when mounting .odbc.ini from host, when published with container it works just fine.

Is there any limitation to mounting system files on native linux (I'm just assuming that this is due to file being required on startup just like some files on Windows, my understanding of linux is quite limited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it, all that was needed was to remove environment variables specifing ODBC.ini and ODBCINST.ini location and use default location.